# Get a word in a table that contains similar words in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two type of strings in a column.

```
DECLARE @t table(parameter varchar(100))

INSERT @t values
('It contains eact01' ),
('It contains preact01')
```

I'm trying to get the strings that contain the word 'eact01'.

My problem is that using the following SELECT, I get also the variables that contain 'preact01', because it contain 'eact01'.

```
SELECT * FROM @t WHERE parameter LIKE '%eact01%'
```

How could I get only the row containing 'eact01'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should find all combinations, any character not being a letter or a number considerer this as a spit character or a new word.

```
SELECT * 
FROM @t
WHERE
  parameter like '%[^0-9a-z]eact01'
  or parameter like '%[^0-9a-z]eact01[^0-9a-z]%'
  or parameter like 'eact01[^0-9a-z]%'
  or parameter = 'eact01'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this-

```
select *
from @t 
where 
    parameter='eact01' 
OR  parameter like '%[^0-9a-z]eact01%' 
OR  parameter like 'eact01[^0-9a-z]%' 
OR  parameter like '%[^0-9a-z]eact01[^0-9a-z]%'
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is just add space:

```
SELECT * FROM @t WHERE parameter LIKE '% eact01%' or parameter LIKE 'eact01%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a string splitter for this. Here is one taken from Aaron Bertrand's [article](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings_XML
(
   @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   RETURN 
   (  
      SELECT Item = y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)')
      FROM 
      ( 
        SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
          + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, '</i><i>') 
          + '</i>').query('.')
      ) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
   );
```

Then, you can use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM @t
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM dbo.SplitStrings_XML(parameter, ' ') s
    WHERE s.Item = 'eact01'
)
```